# Google App Engine + Authentification on Android using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0

using GoogleApiClient from example https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android i can sign in with my g+ account on android mobile device.

I can also get user id with

```
Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String id = currentUser.getId();
```

The question is, how to make secure connection to backend server running on GAE? It is possible to make it by webview, but i don't want to do it this way. I could imagine, that i should send a userId and token to the backend, and from backend verify if this token match the user id, or something like that.

As sample App you could imagine a game, where reached cups are saved on backend and could be read only by authenticated users...

Thanks!